# Add dataframe column to list column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

In the example below, I have countries and their links to different modules in two different format, a dataframe and a list. I would like to add the data (links and the given module) in the dataframe `redf` to the elements of the `Nodes` column of the list `relist` matched by the country names. Is there a way to accomplish this? My expected output is that the list of tables format of the`Nodes` column of `relist` is preserved, but also includes the links and module in `redf`. For e.g. Algeria, the links 2 in module 3 from `redf` would be added to the`Nodes` elements for Algeria, so that its `Nodes` are changed from `` c(`1` = 3, `3` = 5, `4` = 3) `` to `` c(`1` = 3, `2` = 3, `3` = 5, `4` = 3). ``

Reproducible example:

```
redf <- structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina"), module = c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), degs = c(Afghanistan = 3, Albania = 9, Algeria = 3, 
Angola = 2, `Antigua and Barbuda` = 1, Argentina = 37)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

relist <- structure(list(Label = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "C?te d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", 
"Central African Republic", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", 
"China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of", "Colombia", 
"Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", 
"Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", 
"Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Republic of Tanzania", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    Nodes = list(Afghanistan = structure(c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 4L, 
    `6` = 1L), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("2", "3", 
    "6")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), Albania = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
    `2` = 2L, `3` = 2L, `4` = 10L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
        Algeria = structure(c(`1` = 3L, `2` = 4L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 3L
        ), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("1", "2", 
        "3", "4")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), Angola = structure(c(`2` = 3L, 
        `3` = 2L, `4` = 3L, `5` = 1L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
            c("2", "3", "4", "5")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
        `Antigua and Barbuda` = structure(c(`1` = 2L), .Dim = 1L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
            "1"), .Names = ""), class = "table"), Argentina = structure(c(`0` = 2L, 
        `1` = 24L, `2` = 38L, `3` = 25L, `4` = 29L, `5` = 2L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
            c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")), .Names = ""), class = "table"))), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When you say extended, should that be columns or list

Comment: @akrun Preferably they should be added to the list column Nodes, in the same format as the current data entries. Also, see slightly updated redf.

Comment: In your example, I find that the names are getting duplicated when you concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the 'redf by the 'name' column, then use `map2` to loop over the `intersect`ing names of the list and the 'Nodes' `list`, and concatenate

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
lst1 <- map(split(redf[-1], redf$name), deframe)
nm1 <- intersect(names(relist$Nodes), names(lst1))
relist$Nodes[nm1] <- map2(relist$Nodes[nm1], lst1[nm1],
        ~  {v1 <- c(.x, .y)
         v1[order(as.numeric(names(v1)))]
    })
```

---

Or may also this after a join i.e. `right_join` with the 'redf' `by` the `Label` and `name` columns from respective datasets, use `pmap` to loop over the row, and concatenate after creating named vector for 'degs/module' columns

```
library(dplyr)
relist %>% 
   right_join(redf, by = c("Label" = "name")) %>% 
   transmute(Label, Nodes = pmap(list(Nodes, degs, module),
        ~ c(..1, setNames(..2, ..3))))
```

Comment: I think that instead of having the `module` and `link` fields _alongside_ `Nodes`, MoonS wants to nest them _within_ `Nodes`, such that the element for Algeria has a `Label` of `"Algeria"` and a `Nodes` of ```c(`1` = 3, `2` = 4, `3` = 5, `4` = 3, `module` = 1, `links` = 3)```

Comment: Hopefully more clear now, see updated post.